# Jpa Repository queries for multiple values in a column and many to one relationship for Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am new to JPA repository implementation so seeking for help. The normal sql query to get the table items with the condition in column values will be:

```
select * from table t where t.column in('firstvalue','secondvalue','thirdvalue')
```

is there any JPA/CRUD repository equivalence for this?

For the Many to one relationship.

The subquery would be:

```
select * from child_foo where foo_id in(select foo_id from foo where foo_other_value="somevalue")
```

The hibernate implementation for this would be

```
select * from child_foo where child_foo.foo.foo_othervalue:"somevalue"
```

I was wondering what would JPA equivalence for these queries would be(Implementing this in spring boot)

Answer (score 7):

Spring provide you with 2 ways of defining queries in your repositories.

1. [Query Methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.8.x/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods). Basically you can define queries by the name you put to your function.
2. [Named Queries](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.8.x/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query). Here you annotate your method with @Query and you can either write a [JPQL](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/jpa_jpql.htm#:%7E:text=JPQL%20is%20Java%20Persistence%20Query,developed%20based%20on%20SQL%20syntax.) query like in coosta response or use Native SQL setting the nativeQuery to true in your annotation

For example for your query:

`select * from table t where t.column in('firstvalue','secondvalue','thirdvalue')`

You could use:

**Query method**

```
List<User> findAllByNameIn(List<String> names)
```

[Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.8.x/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) is the list of supported keywords

**Named Query**:

```
@Query("select u from User u where u.name in :names")
List<User> findUsersByName(List<String> names)
```

**Native SQL**

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value="SELECT * FROM USER WHERE NAME in ?0")
List<User> findUsersByName(List<String> names)
```

For the one to many mapping you can you the annotation @OneToMany. Here is a [guide](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many) on how it works

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe annotate your jpa repository function with @Query and use your sql query. Something like this:

@Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.id= :id")
User findUserById(string id);

Here's a thorough explanation:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query

Comment: Why not simply use existing getOne ? Or findById ?